# Converting dictionary values to excel the first cell values/names are missing in python

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have created a dictionary in python. After creating it, I wrote it into an excel file. In this file the first cell values/names alone are missing. How can I get the cell value or how can I give the cell a value by default?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
**(missing value)**       a                b           c
-------------------------------------------------------------
name1                  value1           value2      value3
name2                  value1           value2      value3
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have used pandas dataframe to implement this.
The code i have tried is :

```
ab = pd.DataFrame(Dictionary).T 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ExcelFile.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
ab.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index='True')
```

Comment: The problem sounds like it is within the code you used to create the dictionary.

Comment: "Converting dictionary values to Excel" - what does that mean? I am guessing writing a dictionary to a sheet? Please share the code.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the index is unnamed in a DataFrame. When you export it to Excel, it stores it in a separate column, but since the index does not have a name, the column is untitled.

My solution would be to reset the index to its own column, and then to export it to Excel:

```
ab = pd.DataFrame(dicti) 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ExcelFile.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
ab.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True) #Store the index in a column named "Index"
ab.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False) #Omit the now-irrelevant index.
```